# Unable to launch Rstudio from anaconda navigator on cluster

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

**System details**

```
RStudio Edition : Desktop
RStudio Version : rstudio 1.1.456
OS Version : Linux valis.nb.sissa.it 4.15.0-101-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 11 10:07:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
R Version : R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"
```

I installed R using conda as mentioned in the following link : https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/using-r-language/
This was followed by installing Rstudio in the same environment as R. However, I get the following error when I try to launch Rstudio :

```
> (r_env) urangasw@valis:~$ QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 rstudio
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path
> "/home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms" ...
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "eglfs"
>         ]
>     },
>     "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 329219 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "minimal"
>         ]
>     },
>     "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 329219 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "minimalegl"
>         ]
>     },
>     "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 329219 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "offscreen"
>         ]
>     },
>     "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 329219 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at
> "/home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
> Found metadata in lib
> /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so,
> metadata= {
>     "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
>     "MetaData": {
>         "Keys": [
>             "xcb"
>         ]
>     },
>     "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
>     "debug": false,
>     "version": 329219 }
> 
> 
> Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
> QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path
> "/home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/bin/platforms" ... loaded library
> "/home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
> QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on
> "/home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" :
> "Cannot load library
> /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so:
> (libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory)" This application failed to start because it could not find
> or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".
> 
> Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen,
> xcb.
> 
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Aborted (core
> dumped)
```

On noticing that this might be an issue with libEGL.so.1, I ran conda install -c anaconda mesa-libegl-cos6-x86_64 command but the problem persists.

When I run ldd, libEGL.so.1 is not found :

```
(r_env) urangasw@valis:~$ ldd /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffdedcf000)
libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (0x00007fe34f9ca000)
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fe34f6fe000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fe34f4ee000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fe34f96a000)
libxcb.so.1 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fe34f93e000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe34f937000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe34f2e6000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fe34f1bd000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007fe34efb3000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fe34eda1000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fe34ea69000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fe34ea23000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fe34e96e000)
libEGL.so.1 => not found
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fe34e397000)
libQt5DBus.so.5 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007fe34e30d000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fe34dde1000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fe34db55000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe34d936000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe34d7c1000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe34d423000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe34d40f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe34d01e000)
libEGL.so.1 => not found
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fe34ce1a000)
libpcre.so.1 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/./libpcre.so.1 (0x00007fe34cdd3000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe34cbcf000)
libxml2.so.2 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/./libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fe34ca67000)
libuuid.so.1 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/./libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fe34c863000)
libz.so.1 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/./libz.so.1 (0x00007fe34c843000)
libpng16.so.16 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/./libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fe34c80a000)
libicui18n.so.58 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/./libicui18n.so.58 (0x00007fe34c58b000)
libicuuc.so.58 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/./libicuuc.so.58 (0x00007fe34c3d8000)
libicudata.so.58 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/./libicudata.so.58 (0x00007fe34aad6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe34f900000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fe34a8a5000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007fe34a5ef000)
liblzma.so.5 => /home/urangasw/anaconda3/envs/r_env/plugins/platforms/../../lib/././liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fe34a5c6000)
```

The location of libEGL.so.1 file using find / -name "libEGL.so.1*" is at :

```
/home/urangasw/anaconda3/pkgs/mesa-libegl-cos6-x86_64-11.0.7-1/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib64/libEGL.so.1
```

Any idea how I could harness this information to make rstudio work using anaconda navigator?

Please help me go about it. Any suggestions/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: RStudio through Conda is an abandoned project - I strongly recommend against using it. Do a native install of RStudio. Also, you're better off avoiding Anaconda and the `defaults` channel for R work. Conda Forge provides far better coverage of CRAN. I highly recommend [a MambaForge **base**](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge).

Comment: I do not have the sudo privilege to install RStudio since I'm trying to install it on the cluster. Even in case of installing R, I do so by --with-readline=no while ./configure. Any idea how else I can go about it? Thanks for your response :)

Comment: Is RStudio truly essential to use on your cluster (very doubtful)? If so, raise it with your system administrators. Other options are emacs (through ESS package) or Jupyter (install `r-irkernel` in R environment).